# Throws AvroTypeException error while creating AVRO files with data containing date

Tags: file, date, exception, python-3.7, avro

When I was trying to create an AVRO file with data containing a date object, it throws an AvroTypeException error.

This is the schema I have used:
[screen shot of schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcuM1.png)

This is the code-bit writing the data:
[screen shot of code-bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjKk2.png)

This is the error shown while running the code:
[screen shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd9t4.png)

Please find the link [here](https://github.com/nirmalhq/avro-test) to full version of my code I have tried.

*NOTE: Python version: 3.7.10, avro-python3 version 1.10.2*

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`avro-python3` never supported logical types and was abandoned in favor of having the `avro` library support both Python 2 and 3 (and now it only supports Python 3).

To fix the problem you should `pip uninstall avro-python3` and `pip install avro`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Really appreciate your time.